# How to use Represenstive Views to display users representative nodes?

Tags: 7, views, nodes, users

## Main view (User entity):

Fields:

- (Representative node) Content: Nid
- (Representative node) Content: Type
- (Representative node) Content: Post date
- (Representative node) Content: Title
- other fields

Filter criteria:

- user roles, user active

Relationships:

- User: Representative node

## Represantative view (Content based)

Fields:

- Content: Nid

Filter criteria:

- Content: Type (in Innovation, ...)
- Content: Language (= Current user's language)
- Content: Promoted to front page (Yes)

Sort:

- Content: Post date (desc)

Generated query: http://pastebin.com/cvKD3zzB

Error:

> Error message SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of
> bound variables does not match number of tokens

Could someone give me any advice?

Answer (score 1):

The error has to do with a bug related to User: Representative node. Checkout https://www.drupal.org/node/1417090. Comment #35 has a patch for the latest dev version of views that will possibly fix the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Drupal 8 still has problem here is the [related issue with patches available](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2379423)